# Django grouping and filter, ordering

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating small project for our cinema web

I have models

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
class Projections(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.DELETE)
    startshow = models.DateTimeField()
```

Each Movies have several Projections with different startshow.

---

How can I get Movies grouped by name and ordered by first startshow with all projections for that movie ordered by startshow

The list is looking like this:

- Trools: World Tour

  - 2020-11-10 17:00
  - 2020-11-11 17:00
  - 2020-11-12 17:00
- Frozen

  - 2020-11-10 19:00
  - 2020-11-11 19:00
  - 2020-11-12 19:00
- Tennet

  - 2020-11-10 21:00
  - 2020-11-11 21:00
  - 2020-11-12 21:00

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically only should pass the list of `Movies`, and then iterate over the related `Projections`:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Prefetch

def myview(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.annotate(
        first_start=Min('projections__startshow')
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'projections_set',
            Projections.objects.order_by('startshow'),
            to_attr='ordered_projections'
        )
    ).order_by('first_start')
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'movies': movies})
```

In the template you then render this with:

```
<ul>
  {% for movie in movies %}
    <li>{{ movie.name }}</li>
    <ul>
      {% for projection in movie.ordered_projections %}
        <li>{{ projection.startshow }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Movie` instead of <s>`Movies`</s>.

Comment: Thanks... 
That is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

try with something like this:

```
result = {}
for movie in Movies.objects.all():
    movie_projections = movie.projections_set.all().values_list('startshow', flat=True).order_by('startshow')
    movie_projections = [str(x) for x in movie_projections]

    result[movie.name] = movie_projections

print(result)
```

This is a return format of this code:

```
{'Titanic': ['2020-11-22 10:42:09+00:00', '2020-11-23 20:42:09+00:00'], 'Robocop': ['2020-11-22 20:42:23+00:00']}
```